# Quitar label sin que afecte funconamiento HTML5 JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito ayuda amigo, como puedo modificar este código que no me muestre el nombre del video en el label con id info sin que afecte su funcionamiento. gracias de ante mano

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <label id="info"></label>
    <video id="reproductor" controls></video>

    <script>
        window.onload = function playlist(){
        var reproductor = document.getElementById("reproductor"),
        videos = ["video1", "video2"];
        info = document.getElementById("info");

        info.innerHTML = "Vídeo: " + videos[0];
        reproductor.src = videos[0] + ".mp4";
        reproductor.play();

        reproductor.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        var nombreActual = info.innerHTML.split(": ")[1];
        var actual = videos.indexOf(nombreActual);
        actual = actual == videos.length - 1 ? 0 : actual + 1;
        this.src = videos[actual] + ".mp4";
        info.innerHTML = "Vídeo: " + videos[actual];
        this.play();
    }, false);
    }  
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola amigo alanfcm gracias por la respuesta pero al reproducir el primer video no aparece el titulo pero cuando carga el siguiente video se hace visible el label.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias ya borre esa dos lineas pero así solo se reproduce un video.